# -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8943940 while parsing JSON Page to UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsjsonserialization

I have been through many links and fortunately I got many similar links but nothing worked Out.

my array is appearing like this in Output, using NSLog()..

```
products =     (
            {
        cid = 1;
        name = "hello world";
    },
            {
        cid = 2;
        name = "It is an array";
    },
            {
        cid = 3;
        name = "error error";
    },
            {
        cid = 4;
        name = "OMG! still same";
    },
            {
        cid = 5;
        name = "any help";

  ...
  ...
   },
            {
        cid = 130;
        name = "How is the work going on.";
    },
            {
        cid = 131;
        name = "Had a nice lunch";
    }
);
success = 1
```

Code to parse JSON, where "news" is an Array var..

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;
    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Feeds...%@",news);
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Code to display table row, here in "news" value is being displayed by NSLog(); Error comes for NSDictionary.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   NSLog(@"=====%@====",news);
   NSDictionary *myDict = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSArray *myArray = [myDict objectForKey:@"name"];
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
   if (cell==nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
}

for (NSString *str in myArray) {
    cell.textLabel.text = str;
}
   return cell;
```

}

I am not able to find what i'm missing here.., Please help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Actually the error tells that "news" is a dictionary and not an array as you write. Can you please double check the declaration?

Comment: It is dictionary, I realized when i went through @Midhun MP's Answer..But it is displaying only one(first) name two times in table view.

Answer (score 6):

Your JSON structure is something like this:

Dictionary-->Array-->Object (Dictionary).

So you need to do:

1. Extract the Array from the dictionary using the key `product`
2. Extract an object(Dictionary) from the array using the `index`
3. Get the name from the dictionary object using the key `name`

Instead of this:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *myArray = [myDict objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Use:

```
NSArray *myArr = [news objectForKey:@"products"];
cell.textLabel.text = [[myArr objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

**Edit**

Also change your `numberOfRowsInSection` like:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[news objectForKey:@"products"] count];
}
```

Comment: what is "myDict" in your code..NSArray *myArr = [news objectForKey:@"products"];
    NSDictionary *myDict = [myArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];cell.textLabel.text = [[myDict objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"];...this is what you are saying right..

Comment: It is displaying first value (because of index(0)),  for two times,that's it...rather i did some modification also, that didn't go well..NSArray *myArr = [news objectForKey:@"products"];
    NSLog(@"####myArr is %@####",myArr );
    for (id i in myArr) {
        nameArr = [[myArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }
 for (NSString *str in nameArr) {
        cell.textLabel.text = str;
     }...It is throwing an error -[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x716f070

Comment: @pingToThree Why are you doing like this ? use `cell.textLabel.text = [[myArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];`

Comment: Sorry to bother u again..but problem is still same, It is still displaying only first two names only in the tableview..So i thought loop may help, unfortunately it didn't.

Comment: @pingToThree: please post the `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Comment: -(int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    
    return [news count];
}

Comment: @pingToThree: The return type is NSInteger not int. Also I'm not sure why it's not working. Please NSLog the [news count];

Comment: you are right..NSLog(@"%d,%@",[news count],news);..[news count]'s value is 2 but news is displaying normally.Can i mail you this project so you may go through once.

Comment: Check my edited answer it will do the work you need to return array count not dictionary count in numberOfRows

Comment: @pingToThree: I had sent a mail to you with the fix. Please check. As I suspected the issue was with the `numberOfRowsInSection` method. I added the fix in my answer

Answer (score 1):

`news` is a `NSDictionary`, and a dictionary does not have a method `objectAtIndex:`
You have to use instead `[news objectForKey:...];`

Comment: NSLog(@"=====%@====",news);
     NSArray *myArray = [news objectForKey:@"name"];
     NSLog(@"myarray is %@",myArray);, myarray is (null) here and TableView is empty

Comment: You JSON string is parsed into your "news" dictionary. When you want to get the object for a certain key in this dictionary, you have of course to use a key that is defined there. Since we don't know what is in "data", please look up its source for the keys defined there, and use one of them instead of "name". Obviously, "name" is not an existing key.

Answer (score 1):

```
[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

NSMutabledictionary is indexpath.row so add first news in array and that array name add in 
your code and you get nothing an

Answer (score 0):

**Put NSDictionary in Array then use it in Table method**

```
 NSMutableArray *result=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  result = [googleResponse valueForKey: @"products"];


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSMutableDictionary *dt = [result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

**It will Help you !!!!!**